# PHP exif_read_data no longer extracts GPS location

Tags: php, gps, metadata, exif

I just installed composer via homebrew and brew seemed to install a new version of php (5.6.24).  Since then, using exif_read_data extracts other metadata (model, exposure, iso, etc), but no longer extracts GPS info like "GPSLatitude" from photos.

I ran the same photo through exiftool (standalone non-php program) and GPS data does exist in the photo.

PHP is compiled with exif (as some info is pulled), so I'm scratching my head why GPS data is no longer being read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely due to a regression from a security fix that was causing the ext/exif extension to stop parsing in case of an "unknown" format.

This should be fixed in the 7.x branches (7.0.10 and 7.1.0 Beta 1) should contain a proper fix for these, although it was not merged to the 5.x branches, it could likely find its way there.

If you want a patch (which should be fairly easy to convert into 5.x), then I committed it here:
http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=aabcb5481d9e717df77192dab2894468b9fc63b4

Here is a little background on how ext/exif works and what went wrong:

Internally when we parse the exif data, it will read out the standard exif tags as provided by the spec, however certain formats, have certain custom tags. These are usually parsed too, however ext/exif is limited in the sense that we only (in stable branches including 7.1) support 6 formats with extended tags (the list for each format is baked into the extension). This is where the regression comes in. When parsing the EXIF data, it is done in the following order:

- Standard EXIF data
- Look for known formats for parsing custom tags, if a matching signature is found, then parse them
- Parse additional data, like thumbnail, GPS etc

The security fix caused a regression, because you could craft fake signatures and bypass this internally, which could cause invalid reads. The fix would then bail the parsing in case of a signature mismatch in the list of baked in signatures from formats we know, thus stopping to parse and not returning data like thumbnails, causing exif_thumbnail() to essentially not be usable for any but the 6 formats.

The fix currently in the 7.x branches, restores this behavior and simply continues to parse those additional tags, so those functions and other formats we do not directly support, will once again work.

Besides that, in 7.2, I have been adding support for Samsung, Panasonic and DJI specific tags, and I'm currently looking into Sony specific data too. We have a bug report at php.net which sparkled it all in case you are interested in looking more in depth with this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72735. And should this patch not fix your issue, you are more than welcome to submit a bug report so we can look into resolving this.

I hope this was helpful to you, and thanks for helping to make PHP even greater!

Comment: thanks, that seems to be the issue. im not sure how to apply the patch and recompile php myself, but i also need exif GPS for my application (all new uploads on my app are currently broken without GPS).  i'll probably downgrade back to 5.6.23 until i see a later version with the patch applied (hopefully).

thanks again for responding so quickly.

Comment: for the time being, i've switched to a previously installed version.
using brew:  `brew switch php56 5.6.23`

Comment: Same problem with PHP 5.5.9, no GPS tag

Comment: I'm using version 7.2.7 on windows and its not showing the gps and altitude data. Is there a trick tho this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a server you can install a Perl program called exiftool.
https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/
You can put this software in any directory on your server.
I put it in a subdir of my web directory.

With this script you can retrieve the GPS data if exif_read_data does not work on
your PHP version.

```
function get_latlon($img){
  $path="/YOURIMAGES/";
  $path .= $img;
  exec("/directory_of_exiftool/exiftool -gpslatitude -gpslongitude -c \"%.6f\"  $path",$exifdata);
  $lat=$exifdata[0];$lat=str_ireplace("GPS Latitude","",$lat);$lat=str_ireplace("N","",$lat);$lat=trim(str_ireplace(":","",$lat));

  $lon=$exifdata[1];$lon=str_ireplace("GPS Longitude","",$lon);$lon=str_ireplace("E","",$lon);$lon=trim(str_ireplace(":","",$lon));

  if ($lat !=""){$location="$lat,$lon";}

  return $location;
}
```